# Line Manipulation Reformat text Notepad++ or PSPaD

Tags: notepad++, regex, newlines, text-manipulation, pspad

I have about 40,000 lines I need to look like first line - no paragraph marks.

The trouble is, I can't use join lines then use `(\d\D+)& $1\n` to get like line 1 because of numbers inside of sentences.

Can anyone give any hints or tricks?

```
<1IN THE beginning God (prepared,~formed, fashioned, and) created the~heavens 
 <2The earth was without form and an^p 
 ~empty waste, and darkness was upon^p 
 ~the face of the very great deep. The^p 
 ~Spirit of God was moving (hovering,^p 
 ~brooding) over the face of the waters. 
 <3And God said, #1 Let there be light; and^p 
 ~there was light.^p 
 <4And God saw that the light was good^p 
 ~(suitable, pleasant) and He approved it;^p 
 ~and #2 God separated the light from the darkness.^p 
 <5And God called the light 1 Day, and the^p 
 ~darkness He called Night. And #3 there^p 
 ~was evening and there was morning,^p 
 ~one day.^p
```

Comment: You have actual `^p` there or Unix line endings or Windows line endings or what? Also is there an initial space from line 2 onwards or is that a formatting mistake? What about the tildes (~) - shouldn't they be replaced with spaces?

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it in several steps.

If you want the `<n` to start a new line, I'd start by replacing `/^ (\<\d+.*)/` with `$1` (remove the leading space from lines starting `<n`).

Then I would replace `/^(.*)\^p$/` with `$1` (remove the ^p at the end of the line).

Then replace `/^ \~(.*)/` with just a leading space.

Then it might be easiest to remove ALL newlines and finally split the lines wherever there is a `<n`: Replace `/(\<\d+)/` with `\n$1`

Not actually tried this in NP++ though so treat with caution!